# android : what decided edit text default border colour on focus

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two different apps and how  the edittext appears in both are different. In one when i focus , the border is getting an orange colour and in other app its blue. I am not setting background in either the app. So how is the difference coming. Is it the android version selected ?

Comment: may be based on your application theme..that too diffrent applications may be two themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default styling of widgets is controlled by the theme used by the activity. From your described symptoms, my guess is that you have not specified any theme, which means that you will get an orange focus ring on Android 1.x/2.x, a blue border on Android 3.x/4.x, and IIRC a gray border (subject to custom tints) in Android 5.0+.

More tactically, the focus is part of the `EditText` background, which will be a `StateListDrawable` pointing to other drawables for the various states (normal, focused, disabled, etc.).

Comment: .It was due to theme . I had set theme for the activity Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar . I need to maintain the no titlebar theme. So is there a way i can change the edittext focus colour in easy way . I have many views so it is not easy to set the background for each edittext.

Comment: @preetha: "So is there a way i can change the edittext focus colour in easy way" -- why are you worrying about it? Your `EditText` widgets will appear as they do by default on those versions of Android. That being said, changing the `EditText` focus color requires you to create a custom background image for the focused state and a custom `StateListDrawable` that references your custom background image for the focused state. Then, you would create a custom theme that teaches Android to use your `StateListDrawable` for `EditText` backgrounds.

Comment: @preetha: The [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) can help you do some of this for Android 3.0+ (or Android 3.x/4.x, depending on what you are doing for Android 5.0). Using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport will also allow you to use a tint to control the `EditText` colors, going back to API Level 7, but at the cost of changing other aspects of the look-and-feel of your app (and probably conflicting with your `NoTitleBar` requirement).